# Tense of verb in "We demand..."

Tags: tenses, mood

Consider this sentence:

> We demand that the university close all bookstores on Sunday.

The hypothetical "close" is not in the normal present tense "closes" that I would use if I were to describe the university's response:

> The university now closes its bookstores on Sunday.

I believe both sentences are grammatically correct (being a native speaker), but I do not know, formally, why the first is correct.  What is the tense used in the hypothetical clause, and what are the rules for when to apply it?

Comment: *Close* is in the present subjunctive and *closes* is in the present indicative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: Depending on your point of view, you could either call ***close*** there an *unmarked infinitive* or a *subjunctive* form. Bear in mind that increasing numbers of native speakers would inflect it as ***closes*** in the first example. So it's often *I demand he **apologises***, rather than *I demand [that] he **apologise***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've heard it both ways!  But I was pretty sure that the way I wrote it is "more correct," no?

Comment: thirtythreeforty: I'm sure you'll still find plenty of grammarians (particularly, *older* ones) who support your idea of "more correct". But it's increasingly seen as an antiquated usage - I'm not convinced English *ever* really had a "subjunctive" like that outside of Latin-based academia, and you encounter it less and less these days.

Comment: Fair enough.  Things like subjunctive "if it were" do seem to be shoehorned into the language (although again, such phrases that don't use the subjunctive sound wrong to me).

Comment: They're not shoehorned in; they're grandfathered in. They're old ways of speaking that are still around in special idioms and archaic constructions, like _dost thou_ and _so mote it be_. It pleases some people to call it subjunctive, because it reminds them of Latin subjunctive, which was a normal productive part of the language, unlike English.

Comment: +1 Very interesting question! I'd consider it stylistic to some extent, but I think @Anonym is on the right track. Anonym, could you please consider elaborating on your comment by posting it as an answer?

Comment: If you think that the English subjunctive is an invention of Latin grammarians, I urge you to look at any Old English verbal paradigm (e.g. *etan* 'to eat' http://hord.ca/projects/eow/grammar/verb.php?id=4067&output=macron). It was very much alive and well, remaining a vital part of the language through Middle English and into Early Modern English. You can scarcely read through one of Shakespeare's monologues without encountering at least a few times.

Comment: @TimWard Though it appears to a command, this is not in the imperative mood. We no longer use the third-person imperative in English, only the second-person. A third-person imperative would look something like this: *If any man see this comment, do he read it.*

Comment: @Anonym Heaven forbid that we should still use third-person imperatives! :)

Comment: @tchrist that's it!  I didn't know enough to be able to search for that question directly, but I do now :)